# Powershell cant understand "bcdedit"

Tags: powershell, bcdedit

When I try to run in CMD `bcdedit` command is working.
When I try to run it in PowerShell I get this: `The term 'bcdedit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`
But in manuals and tutorials `bcdedit` working fine in PowerShell.
Why my PowerShell did not recognize `bcdedit`?

System: Windows 7 x64 SP3

Comment: Did you make sure you are not running into a x64 CMD vs. x86 PowerShell issue? (or vice versa)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two versions of powershell.exe, one 32-bit and one 64-bit.

In the 32-bit version, the path C:\windows\system32 actually refers to C:\windows\SysWOW64.

bcdedit.exe only exists in the "real" 64-bit system32 and cannot be found in a 32-bit powershell console.

To determine which version of powershell you are running you can run this command:

```
PS C:\> [intptr]::Size
4
```

On a 32-bit console the size is 4 and on a 64-bit console the size is 8.